# setting a textFields inputView to prevent keyboard from appearing doesn't work with split keyboard

Tags: ios

I have a textField which I want to edit by using a custom input view within a popOver. So I am preventing the keyboard from appearing but setting a dummy view for the textViews input view, i.e

```
UIView* dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];    
[self.textFieldStartBid setInputView:dummyView];
```

This works fine, I tap on the textField, the keyboard stays hidden and the popoverController appears. The problem arises if you had previously split the keyboard, now when you tap on the textField I get a bordered transparent view appearing at the bottom of the screen which covers the entire width and is about 50 pixels high.

I have more than one viewController using this technique to hide the keyboard and all VCs have this exact same issue with the split keyboard.

It seems I am half way there to stopping the split keyboard from appearing but not fully, has any experienced this or no or any possible solutions?

Thanks,
Stewart.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)` for your `dummyView` initialization:

```
UIView* dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

This worked fine for me.